# reset wireless keyboard shortcut

Tags: wireless

I would like to define a keyboard shortcut that resets my wireless adapter.
I know it is possible in the terminal with sudo ifconfig, but for the keyboard shortcut, I can't provide the password for sudo.

Are there other commands that can do the job without root privileges?

Answer (score 2):

Network Manager has a nice CLI tool, `nmcli`, that does not require root privilege. You can reset wifi with

```
nmcli radio wifi off && nmcli radio wifi on
```

Answer (score 1):

```
wifi off
wifi on
```

seems to do the job. 
I wanted also to splash some text to the foreground but it's not so important. Any ideas about how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

No they are not, but you can call `gksudo` instead of sudo to have a window showed up that asks for your password.